# How can i only get sum of consecutive numbers in a list

Tags: python-3.x

How do I add only consecutive numbers in a list together?

```
input1 = [4,4,5,6,2,2,2,4,3,5,5]
result1 = [8,6,10]
```

Here is the code I am attempting to use to do so

```
# sum of the consecutive elements. 
  
# Function to print alternate sum 
input1 = [4,4,5,6,2,2,2,4,3,5,5]

result1 = [8,6,10]

#for i in range(0,len(um),0)
#   num+= num[i] + num[i-1]

def append_sum(lst):
        total=[]
        i=0
        while i <len(lst[i-1]):
            if (lst[i] == lst[i-1]):
                total.append(lst[i] + lst[i-1])
                i+=1
                print (total)
                append_sum([4,4,5,6,2,2,2,4,3,5,5])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby

input1 = [4,4,5,6,2,2,2,4,3,5,5]
res = []
for k, g in groupby(input1):
    g = list(g)
    if len(g) > 1:
        res.append(sum(g))
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[8, 6, 10]
```